# KDE behaviour without using Kubuntu?

Tags: unity, kde

Is there a way of getting the KDE behaviour using Unity?.
 I mean the jumping Icons and everything but without installing KDE alongside Gnome or Unity.

Comment: just the bouncing icons?

Comment: @Mateo Mostly them.

Comment: I think CCSM may be useful, but I don't use that tool.

Comment: @MrVaykadji I appreaciate your comment but I haven't find that option anywhere in Compiz.